# Windows 7 - Drive not recognized? - ISO installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, usb

Been fiddling with this for a good bit now and I'm starting to get a headache I've been browsing the internet for the better part of 2 hours trying to get the necessary assistance to finish my windows 7 installation on a new blank seagate 500GB HDD.

The USB is recognized and the windows 7 installation menu shows but the hard drive is not selectable on the install screen.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RomH.png]

I've read something about needing mass storage drivers? I can only find an exe for this and nothing I can put onto a USB and open.

I'm also seeing an unknown cd rom in my boot menu - I'm taking a wild leap assuming this is the new blank hard drive?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDNvP.png]

HP - P2 1033W is the model.

Comment: Sorry its not listed on the install list or on the boot list? As the screenshot shows the boot list.

Comment: The screenshot('s) show both please read it all I explained it already.

Comment: There was only one screenshot when I posted that comment... Its not driver related its due to bios settings. You will need to go in to your bios and check what mode the drive is set to AHCI (if not available check what modes you have and post back) If this is not the cause then its due to the drive already having an unsupported partition on it and needs reformatting.

Answer (score -2):

I will answer your question with questions, Im sorry, but...
Does the BIOS (F2 at powerup) see the hard drive?
Have you tried to clicked Load Driver as shown on screenshot?

[image]

Maybe it needs the SATA drivers installed or similar.

If ide hard drive or sata hard drive is not detected  by windows 7   do this.
download the sata or ide controller driver to usb or floppy or portable drive. "must be unzipped and in a folder'

boot up windows 7 from cd! (or usb)

see the option load a driver?

now browse file

choose it  and install it.

now your drive is visual and usable!

choose the drive hard u want windows 7 on!

done! keep going with install of  win7!

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1f3df40d-987b-417f-bd02-475f3291e50f/seagate-hard-drives-not-detected-by-the-windows-7-installer?forum=w7itproinstall

Comment: Problem is that I don't have the drivers and cannot find them.

Comment: Can you give us some more details regarding your HDD? You can find the drivers here normally http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/